# Can public force.com sites be accessed from "restricted countries"

Tags: security

As from the summer 15 release, Salesforce started blocking users from logging in from "restricted countries" like Cuba and Iran. (http://trust.salesforce.com/trust/blocked)

Does this also apply to force.com pages that don't require any login?
So where it are just guest users?

Comment: Somehow my ISP have me a 95.82.*.* ip address, which some geo IP services think are in Iran, and from said IP address, I was unable to access any Salesforce content apart from Salesforce.com